# What makes a form preventing from being hidden?

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

I'm new to C# but working on a very large C# project. I am not the original author of any source code of the project. I have a form which I'm trying to hide after a button is pressed on the form. I tried both of the following:

```
this.Hide();

this.Visible = false;
```

Neither makes the form hide. I'm wondering what makes a form not to be hidden.

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and VS 2008 on Windows XP SP 3.

Comment: @puzo: why `form.Show();` will make the form hidden?

Comment: I apologize, I read the question sloppy.

Comment: @Donotalo Tell me how many times **this.Visible=true** or **this.Show()** occur and where (post code if possible)?

Comment: Does your form class derive directly from `Form` or was there a base class that your company wrote that you derive from? I'm wondering if that base class has functionality that cancels out the `Hide` method. It's not virtual, so they couldn't override it directly, but there are a zillion events on a form which I'm not 100% familiar with, so maybe one of them allows you to cancel the event when you call `Hide()`.

Comment: @AVD: checked. neither `this.Visible=true` or `this.Show()` is found. totally weird.

Comment: @Joe Enos: the form is directly derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class.

Comment: @Donotalo I guess a follow up - those events can still be subscribed to externally. When the instance of your form is created, does the calling code attach any event handlers to any of its events? (i.e.: `var form = new MyForm(); form.OnDeactivate += SomeMethod; form.Show();`) I can't tell which events would be applicable, but there are a half dozen or so that are involved in showing/hiding a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both below ways should work. Not sure why you say this.Hide() not working. Make sure 'this' is the actual form that you want to hide.

```
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
  this.Visible = false;
```

or

```
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this code

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
Hide();
```

Comment: may be some where else in your project you are writing show(), otherwise definitely it should hide() and minimize

Answer (score 1):

```
this
```

reference to the current instance.
For example, if you're in the ButtonClick event function of MainForm then this.Close() will close the MainForm. If you want to close another form, you should reference it such as instantiating it

```
SecondForm secondForm = new SeondForm(); 
form.Close();
```

Comment: i'm actually trying to hide `this` form. `this` is not referring to the main form in the code i'm working.